# Jboss Application servlet 7.x deployment query?

Tags: deployment, jboss7.x, ejb-3.1

I was using jboss 5 so far my project. My project used following technology jsp,servlet,ejb3,postgres and hibernate. Now i have a plan to migrate jboss 7. i need some information related to persistence.xml and datasource. because jboss 7 directory structure looking completely different. please give a suggestion how to migrate? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a lot more details on your setup for this to one just one simple answer, but I can provide these links as an answer:

- https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+AS5+or+AS6+to+AS7
- https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+AS5+or+AS6+to+AS7